# 3 different ways to check the number of pages on site gives 3 different answers

Tags: sitemap, google-xml-sitemaps

I entered this command into Google:

```
site:g33ktalk.com
```

And it returned 659 pages.

But when I created a sitemap with this service: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ it showed me 498 pages crawled.

And when I made the sitemap with the Wordpress default sitemap generator, it showed under 400 pages.

Would anyone know why this happens and what is the correct count? Is it a crawling problem? If so, how would I begin debugging it so that all 600+ pages can be crawled?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible mistake: depends on what you mean by 'page'. Search engines would count archives pages as pages, whereas WordPress will only count post-type page, not archives nor posts.

Comment: thanks, but what exactly is an archive page?

Comment: That's basically what you see when browsing your posts by tags, categories, author… To WordPress it doesn't count as a page as it would to search engines, because WordPress 'pages' are a specific post format, not merely HTML files.

Comment: Ah got it. But nevertheless, my Google webmaster account shows under 400 pages indexed. Shouldn't it have more pages indexed?

Comment: Not necessarily, you may have somes pages that exist but are not linked to anything. A page without any link to reach it won't be indexed: how would robots find it?

A smooth solution would be to generate a sitemap directly from WordPress, I think you can do that using some plugins or a custom page Template.

Comment: yeah that is what I was thinking. I need to figure out which pages are not the ones linked.  That was at the heart of my question.